# Why did Mother Teresa use the phrase "it is a poverty"?

Tags: idioms, word-usage, quotations

I frequently see bumper stickers with quotations attributed to Mother Teresa that begin with the words "It is a poverty," for [example](http://tennesseerighttolife.org/products/bumper_stickers.htm):

> It is a poverty to decide that a child must 
>   die so that you may live as you wish.

Leaving aside the politics of the sentiment which are obviously irrelevant, why "it is a poverty"?  I think it's safe to infer that the intention is negative--roughly "it's a bad thing that"--but the phrase is distinctly off-sounding to my (native Western AmE-speaking) ear, as if it were a calque of an idiom in another language.  The closest phrase I can think of that sounds like idiomatic English to me is "It is a poor thing," although even that is a bit formal and old-fashioned.

Mother Teresa spoke English as a second language according to her Wikipedia entry--is there something in particular about her education or origins that would account for this odd expression?  I know Google is not a reliable source for collecting data on usage patterns, but it is still interesting that a search on the quoted phrase "it is a poverty" turns up literally *no* other results where the phrase is used in this sense, only references to the original quote.

Comment: Being someone who worked with the poor most of her life, and hence may be considered an expert on poverty, she was likely attempting to create a turn of phrase that would lend additional rhetorical weight to the point she was making.  More specifically, she was likely coining an aphorism: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/aphorism

Comment: My immediate, intuitive understanding would be that ‘it is a poverty’ here means something along the lines of ‘to do this is to make yourself [morally] poor’.

Comment: It sounds to me more like it was meant to mean "it is a shame that..."

Comment: Combining two sub-entries from Collins **poverty** ... noun ... 2. scarcity or dearth: _a poverty of wit_
and [RHK Websters](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/poverty)  **poverty** ... noun ... 2. deficiency of necessary or desirable ingredients, qualities, etc.
would seem to license this count usage.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  I can guess at the intended meaning.  My question is why she said it in such an unusual way.  (Edited my question to make this clearer.)

Comment: It is not uncommon for someone making a profound public statement, to coin a unique expression that assists in the statement's identification. In *I've been to the mountaintop*, did Martin Luther King actually mean he had climbed a mountain?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your suggestion of "it is a poor thing" and English not being her first language (or the first language of the people she talked to).

Comment: Mother Teresa is a literal saint.  The only editor she answered to is God.

Comment: According to the site that claims to be the official site of Mother Teresa she *did not* actually say that, or it has been paraphrased. http://www.motherteresa.org/08_info/Quotesf.html

Comment: @amdn Interesting.  That makes it even weirder.

Answer (score 6):

[I should've checked the OED first](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/149126?redirectedFrom=poverty).

> 4. Deficiency in an appropriate or desired quality; inferiority, paltriness, meanness; = poorness n. 3. Formerly also as a count noun.

So it's the same usage as in *poverty of imagination* (which is something of a journalistic stock phrase, if not rising quite to the level of idiom), or (to give a silly example) *I have a poverty of self-control, so I ate all the cookies.*  "Poverty" in this sense without "of" immediately following is archaic, but not unprecedented:

> ▸a1387   J. Trevisa tr. R. Higden Polychron. (St. John's Cambr.) (1865) I. 11 (MED),   I knewe myn owne pouert, and schamede..after so noble spekers..to putte forþ my bareyn speche.
>
> a1425  (▸c1395)    Bible (Wycliffite, L.V.) (Royal) (1850) Prov. vi. 32   He that is avouter schal leese his soule for the pouert [a1382 E.V. miseise; L. inopiam] of herte.
>
> c1450  (▸c1400)    Bk. Vices & Virtues (Huntington) 130 (MED),   Þe first degree of mekenesse is for to knowe his pouertes and his defautes.
>
> 1597   Bacon Ess. v. f. 23v,   By imputing to all excellencie in compositions a kind of pouertie or..a casualty or ieopardy.

Comment: Mother T may also have been playing off people's familiarity with the more common expression "It's a pity that..."

Comment: @ErikKowal: Mother T? Really?

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction - Problem?

Comment: @ErikKowal: Just never heard her being referred to like that.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction - I hadn't either, but if you Google *"Mother T" Teresa,* you should bring up circa 13,000 hits (or at least I did here), a considerable number of which feature the term "Mother T".

Comment: You should be able to self-accept when you come back.

Answer (score 0):

The quote is incomplete. I don't recall the exact wording, but is was something like, "It is a particular poverty of the spirit to decide ..." When the bumper sticker first came out, I noticed that version of the quote really did not make much sense, unlike the full quote. Unfortunately, the bumper sticker version is the one that has taken hold.